# Undefiend when alerting div inner text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I created a PHP page and I want to select inner text of a div and alert it with jquery. but when doing it, it alerts "undefined". what's the problem?

hear is my code:

```
<div class="day">1</div><div class="day">2</div><div class="day">3</div><div class="day">4</div><div class="day">5</div><div class="day">6</div><div class="day">7</div><div class="day">8</div><div class="day">9</div><div class="day">10</div><div class="day">11</div><div class="day">12</div><div class="day">13</div><div class="day">14</div><div class="day">15</div><div class="day">16</div><div class="day">17</div><div class="day">18</div><div class="day">19</div><div class="day">20</div><div class="day">21</div><div class="day">22</div><div class="day">23</div><div class="day">24</div><div class="day">25</div><div class="day">26</div>

<div class="day">27</div><div class="day">28</div><div class="day selected default">29</div>   

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    alert($(".day.selected.default").innerText);
}
</script>
```

it should alerts:  29

I also used innerHtml and textContent. but they doesn't work.

Comment: you just missing the `)` in end of ready function and replace `innerText` to `text()` or `html()`

Comment: yes. I should use text(). thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
alert($(".day.selected.default").text());
```

OR

```
alert($(".day.selected.default").html());
```

`innerText` and `innerHtml` is javascript object property here you are used `jQuery` so you have to use either `html()` or `text()`.

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/md1087ba/)</kbd>**

Comment: actually its a javascript object property, `alert($(".day.selected.default")[0].innerText);` will also work

Comment: @Ghost actually it is Web API DOM Element property, which is accessed using JavaScript, but whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

use below code . you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get data with html elements+ text or [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get only text.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  alert($(".day.selected.default").html());
 });
</script>

  or 

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    alert($(".day.selected.default").text());
  });
 </script>
```